# How to make a changing color shape?

Tags: html

Hey I know how to make rainbow background, it is easy

```
<html>
<center>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 5s;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];

var i = 1;

window.setInterval(function(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
i++;
if (i === colors.length){
i=0;
}
}, 5000);
</script>
</body>
</center>
</html>
```

But do you know how to make for example a changing color circle or other shapes using this code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you google around? Is there a reason you used javascript in your example? You can do this with css only, for example:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nohoid/pen/kIfto)

```
.wrapper { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
background-size: 1800% 1800%;

-webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-z-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow { 
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
```

Just use div with class "wrapper" and background should change with colors your set in css.